# Pool pump man-in-the-middle SDA/SCL with ESP32

Tags: c++, esp32, i2c, espressif

Hey all I have found some code on GitHub that works with my pool pump but it seems my model is a little newer than the one they used on on their GitHub. Most things seem to work **but what doesn't is that the buttons on the control board do not seem to call out correctly to the main board.**

The code for the buttons look to be this:

```
#define BUTTON_BOOST        0x44
#define BUTTON_TIMER        0x46
#define BUTTON_POWER        0x4C
#define BUTTON_LOCK         0x4E
#define BUTTON_SELF_CLEAN   0x74
```

The bulk of the data **seems** to be coming from `void IRAM_ATTR Core1( void* p) {`...

And **perhaps** within that is the button code?

```
if (sendingKeyCode) {                  
   if (totalBitsSent < 8) {                    
       digitalWrite(dataPin, (buttonStatus << totalBitsSent) & 0x80 ? HIGH : LOW);
       totalBitsSent++;
   }
   // FALLING edge 8 while sending keycode
   else if (totalBitsSent == 8) {
       // Receive ACK
       pinMode(dataPin, GPIO_MODE_INPUT);                        
       digitalWrite(dataPin, HIGH);
       totalBitsSent++;                    
   }
   // FALLING edge 9 while sending keycode
   else {
       sendingKeyCode = false;
       totalBitsSent = 0;
   }
}
```

I did the rest api call (http://192.168.1.173:8080/api/v1/intex/swg/status) and got this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "display": {
            "status": "ON",
            "brightness": 3,
            "current_code": "."
        },
        "status": {
            "power": "STANDBY",
            "boost": "OFF",
            "sleep": "OFF",
            "o3_generation": "OFF",
            "pump_low_flow": "OFF",
            "low_salt": "OFF",
            "high_salt": "OFF",
            "service": "OFF"
        },
        "mode": {
            "working": false,
            "programming": false
        }
    }
}
```

So I know it can communicate with it just fine. And I also did this debug rest api call (http://192.168.1.173:8080/api/v1/intex/swg/debug) and got this back:

```
{
    "data": {
        "powerStatus": "0x01",
        "statusDigit1": "0x00",
        "statusDigit2": "0x02",
        "statusDigit3": "0x00",
        "displayingDigit1": "0x00",
        "displayingDigit2": "0x02",
        "current_code": ".",
        "readBuffer": "[0X68, 0X00], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X6C, 0X00], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X6A, 0X02], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X68, 0X00], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X6C, 0X00], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X6A, 0X02], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X68, 0X00], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X6C, 0X00], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X6A, 0X02], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X68, 0X00], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X6C, 0X00], [0X48, 0X01], [0X6A, 0X02], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X68, 0X00], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X6C, 0X00], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X6A, 0X02], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X68, 0X00], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X6C, 0X00], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X6A, 0X02], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X68, 0X00], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X6C, 0X00], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X6A, 0X02], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X68, 0X00], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X6C, 0X00], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X6A, 0X02], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X68, 0X00], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X6C, 0X00], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X6A, 0X02], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X68, 0X00], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X6C, 0X00], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X6A, 0X02], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X68, 0X00], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X6C, 0X00], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X6A, 0X02], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X68, 0X00], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X6C, 0X00], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X6A, 0X02], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X68, 0X00], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X6C, 0X00], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X6A, 0X02], [0X48, 0X01], [0X68, 0X00], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X6C, 0X00], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X6A, 0X02], [0X49, 0XFF], [0X48, 0X01], [0X00, 0X00]",
        "compilation_date": "Apr 27 2023",
        "compilation_time": "16:20:36",
        "otaUpdating": false,
        "removeWifiConfig": false,
        "machineON": true,
        "wifiReconnecting": false,
        "readingMaster": true,
        "sendingKeyCode": false
    }
}
```

**Would be great if someone more knowledgeable at binary and SDA/SCL would help me find my buttons binary code so that I can send that code to the pool pumps main controller.**

The GitHub> https://github.com/jingsno/intex-swg-iot

Comment: `do not seem to call out correctly` ... they either do, or do not ... there is no `seem to` ... print the button code that is received and adjust your code to respond to the code that is received